# Performance testing - analysing Graph results in Jmeter

Tags: automation, load, jmeter, performance-testing, stress-testing

Am new to Jmeter and iran the test successfully. Now I'd like to understand what the results mean and what is classed as good/bad measurements, and what can be suggested to improve the results. Below is a table of the results collated in the Summary report of Jmeter.

Can anyone help me understand these results?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**To improve results** you'll want to look at the tests you run to generate these metrics and ask "does this test accurately measure your sites performance".

- Are you globally (or regionally) balancing your tests? if you are on the same network as your server you will not be measuring how it responds to people across the country.
- Are the tests spaced out over time, with startup delays, and such
- Is 1800 really enough users to test the site
- Are all the pages tested
- Are you "Retrieving All Embedded Resources" in your http requests
- If you rely on Javascript, and the use of Javascript to pull data into your pages (like with AJAX) you should test with script recording because just a HTTP request will not test data that is AJAX'ed in later.

**Are your results good or bad** First you'll want to have a good foundation on how response time impacts how long users stay on your site. Here is a starter
https://blog.kissmetrics.com/loading-time/?wide=1
e.g. If your pages load in 3 seconds 10% of users leave because thats too long for them, well, you have to decide if that is good, or bad for your company.

**Understanding the graph** Here is some info from the jmeter site on this particular graph: 
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Graph_Results

**at a glance** Generally, it looks like your response time is fine, it almost seems so low that it hits you may not be covering everything necessary to test (see "to improve results") I do see your deviation is increasing as load increases, so there may be some small issue related to that.

Answer (score 1):

1. JMeter comes with various samplers that can be used for analysis. You can have some additional and useful samplers from JMeter Plugins site.
2. In order to begin with analysis you need to have a look at 90th Percentile Response Time for each request.
3. Check if response time meets SLA. Also check for throughput you are getting.
4. Have different sets of test so that you can find relation with growing number of users, response time and throughput.
5. Aggregate Report Sampler can be used for this. If you find some requests are not meeting SLAs then run test with those requests, add some profilers, take thread dumps to analyze the bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @rachna bafna ...here i want to explain the obtained Summary Report to my higher authority..could u please explain whether the site is performing well and i want to explain the each fields in Summary Report. can u please help in this

Comment: I need more details of test parameters. How many threads, ramp up, if there are timers you used and duration of test. Also get an aggregate report.